# Type cast int parameter of function to char

Tags: c++

> The PrintLines function must have exactly three formal parameters, all of type int.
>
> From left-to-right the parameters in the 3-parameter version of PrintLines represent the value of a character to be printed, the number of times the character is to be printed on a line, and the number of lines to be produced.
>
> For example, PrintLines('C', 5, 2) would result in:
>
> CCCCC
>
> CCCCC
>
> The PrintLines function uses a type int parameter to represent this character. But note that when called in the presence of a function prototype all compatible arguments are converted to the type of the corresponding function parameter. This means that even if you use a type char variable to obtain the desired character from the user, it will automatically get converted to type int if passed to a function having a type int parameter. However, to avoid a possible compiler warning use a type cast when passing such an argument. Also, always declare functions to return type void unless returning a value would serve a meaningful purpose.

My problem is that I don't know how to correctly type cast the "a" parameter. The requirement is that PrintLines accepts three int parameters but if I enter a non-integer for parameter "a" the program crashes. I tried to type cast the "a" variable in the prototype, the function header and the output. There is some commented code that I've included to show what I've tried so far. The code compiles but I think there is a run-time/logical error.

Can anyone please help?

Here is the code for main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int a ;
int b ;
int c ;

void PrintLines( int, int, int ) ;

int main(void)
{

  //cin >> (char)a >> b >> c ;
  cin >> a >> b >> c ;
  cout  << '\n' ;
  //PrintLines( (char)a, b, c ) ;
  PrintLines( a, b, c ) ;
  cout  << '\n' ;

  system("pause");
  return 0;

}
```

Here is the code for PrintLines.cpp

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

//void PrintLines( char a, int b, int c )
//void PrintLines( (char) a, int b, int c )
void PrintLines( int a, int b, int c )
{
  for(int i = 0; i < c;  i++)
  {

    for(int j = 0; j < b; j++)
    {
      //cout << (char) (a - 48);
      //cout<< (char) a << '\n' ;
      cout << a ;
    }

    cout << '\n' ;
  }     

}
```

Comment: I checked out this web page but I can't connect the dots. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/

Comment: Any professor that forces you to declare a "print" function and use an `int` instead of a `char` or a `std::string` is not a professor you want to take a class from.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `cout <<` with an `int` you get a number output, not a character. You need to typecast the parameter to a `char`.

```
cout << (char) a;
```

The other problem is that you're *reading* the character as an integer. If you make `a` a `char` instead of `int`, it will be read as a single character and will be automatically upcast to `int` in the function call.

Answer (score 0):

Use static_cast!

```
cout << static_cast<char>(a);
```

Way better to use the correct cast instead of c-style casts